# How do I make an ASP.NET Application wait for Task to complete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have an application that queries data in the background, building a local version of it to be queried by the application.

I am using `Task.Run()`
I am using an `AutoResetEvent` to signal the Task to terminate when shutting down.

I start the build of the local data in `Application_Start`.
I am trying to `Wait` for the exit in `Application_End`

Code that I have in `Application_Start`

```
    private Task SalesDataTask = null;
    private AutoResetEvent SalesTerminate = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        // - removed - AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        DateTime eleven = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(23);
        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now < eleven ?
            eleven - DateTime.Now :
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date.AddHours(23) - eleven;
        int hours24 = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        {   // scope variables...
            string filename = GetSalesDataPath(DateTime.Now);
            if (!File.Exists(filename))
            {
                // create today's file.
                SalesDataTask = Task.Run(async () => { await WriteSalesDataToFile(filename); });
            }
            else SalesDataTask = Task.Run(() => { return; });
        }

        System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(state =>
            {
                // create tomorrows file
                SalesDataTask.Wait();
                string filename = GetSalesDataPath(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
                SalesDataTask = Task.Run(async () => { await WriteSalesDataToFile(filename); });
            }, null, diff.Milliseconds, hours24);

        Application["WaitForFile"] = new WaitForFile(this.WaitForFileTasks);
    }
```

And `Application_End`

```
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        SalesTerminate.Set();
        SalesDataTask.Wait();
    }
```

The code that is executed by the `Task` thread

```
    async private Task WriteSalesDataToFile(string path)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new System.IO.IOException("File already exists");
        }

        var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("SalesData");

                await FMEext.QuerySalesData("dom", (x) =>
                {
                    // callback to handle a block of 
                    // data that is fetched from the REST service
                    x.Elements().ToList().ForEach(e =>
                    {
                        writer.WriteRaw(e.ToString());
                    });
                    // return true to continue processing
                    // return false to terminate processing.
                    return !SalesTerminate.WaitOne(10, true);
                }).ConfigureAwait(false);

                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue that I have is the Application terminates before my `Task` thread has the chance to complete it "termination".

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: If you're going to use Tasks, probably a good idea to [learn async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

Comment: @mason what is wrong with the way it is used here?

Comment: It's too long to explain here really, and I'm probably not the best person for it. But if you read the link I provided, it talks about the correct way to do it.